# Facebook platform: what data can I get?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get some data from companies' Facebook pages, but I don't know what kind of data I can expect. [Here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) is just a small set of properties I can use, although I can see that I can get more according to their official example:

```
{
   "id": "19292868552",
   "name": "Facebook Platform",
   "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/50414_19292868552_7650_s.jpg",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/platform",
   "category": "Product/service",
   "website": "http://developers.facebook.com",
   "username": "platform",
   "founded": "May 2007",
   "company_overview": "Facebook Platform enables anyone to build social applications on Facebook and the web.",
   "mission": "To make the web more open and social.",
   "fan_count": 1522363
}
```

On the official site it is written:

> Pages in specific categories have
>   additional fields depending on
>   category.

But what does that mean? Is there a finite set of properties that can be put on a page, or can a company choose what they want to put? Where can I get the complete list of fields that can be on a page?

Thanks,

Ivan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a page inside Facebook, it lets you choose which type of page you want to create e.g. product, service, company, etc.

Depending on the category that you choose, I guess that there will be some instrinsic information fields for your page. Anyway, I don't think that one category is much different than the others, you should be fine with the standard fields that you have outlined in your question.

Comment: The thing is that in the official Facebook Developers site it says that possible fields are id, name, category and likes, and in the example above there are website, founded, company overview, mission... I just want to know when I can expect those fields and if there are more fields on some other pages.

Comment: I think that the site explains the fields common to all types of pages. Those that you have mentioned are from a certain type only. If you don't find which fields has each type, you can always create your own pages and try with them.